# Connect Hive Kerberos authentication using pyhs2 python

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, kerberos

I am trying to connect to Hive with Kerberos authentication. But I am getting an error 'NotImplementedError: authMechanism is either not supported or not implemented'

I guess I need to set authMechanism to Kerberos somehow.

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='wx0000',

                   port=10000,

                   authMechanism="Kerberos",

                   user='xxxxx',

                   password='******',) as conn:
```

Answer (score 0):

From the source authMechanism is case sensitive, so you'll need it to be "KERBEROS".

Answer (score 0):

This connection string will work as long as the user running the script has a valid kerberos ticket or key tab:

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='beeline_hostname',
                    port=10000,
                    authMechanism="KERBEROS") as conn:

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
            print cur.getDatabases()
```

Username, password and any other configuration parameters are not passed through the KDC.